# Do I need to add a reference to the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting package in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

Do I need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` package in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app?

After an update from the ASP.NET Core 2.2 to the ASP.NET Core 3.1 I removed the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` accidentally, but everything continued to work as it worked before. E.g. the `using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;` line does not throw an error.

My guess is that having the project type `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` allowed me to remove the line `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />`. But I was not able to find a documented proof of that.

Another possible reason why I am not getting any errors after the removal of the `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />` is because I have the `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />`

Comment: See [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Did you do a clean build?  Core is bundle differently from Net.  In some cases you do need to add additional libraries for code to compile.  It is always better to make copy of what works a do a new build of everything to make sure there are no issues.  The Net compiler dependencies don't automatically do a clean build after targeting a different version of Net/Core.

Comment: @jdweng, ofc I did. I even run the tests and checked the API manually.

Comment: @KirkLarkin, that is what I was looking for. Thanks. Also, I found more details here: https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2018/08/29/netcore-primitives-2/. Should I remove my question?